# React-Bootstrap | My own examples look different to the documentation

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `Forms` in React-Bootstrap, but when I copy paste the exact code from the documentation, my form is different to theirs.

I followed the [installation guide](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) running `npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.1.1` in my terminal. In my `package.json`, I have `"bootstrap": "^5.1.1"` and `"react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.1"` as dependencies. I also have `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` in my `index.js`.

But when I run the first example from the [`Forms` documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/)

```
<Form>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      We'll never share your email with anyone else.
    </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
  </Form.Group>
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
```

I get this

[image]

Instead of this
[image]

How do I go about making my output look like the documentation?

Comment: There is a chance that the Documentation could be outdated and using an obsolete version of React-Bootstrap, are you sure you”re using the same version as the documentation? The only real way that this could give you a different result from documentation is if you haven’t included all of the dependencies or the dependencies you’re using are different versions that the documentation. Aside from this I don’t see how the same code could provide two different results

Comment: You need to put the `<Form>` in a some sort of a container element, e.g. the `<Container>`, and style that accordingly (margin, border, etc.). Although I don't understand why you got all the fields centered -- it's not clear just from the snippet you posted.

Comment: I've put wrapped `<Form>` in `<Container>` which has made the margins reasonable, but the fields are still centered. That code snippet is literally all I have. It's inside App.js. `function App() { return ( <Container>...</Container>) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try including this CSS in your index.html file just above title tag.

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">`

and this script at the bottom of inside body in index.html.

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: I don't have an `index.html` file. I only have an `index.js` and `index.css`

Comment: You must be having it inside public folder. If it is not present inside public then send me your folder structure so that I may suggest where to put this code block.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. i've added those two but my output is still different.